# Flutter app not running showing only "Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock"

Tags: android, ios, intellij-idea, flutter

When I hit run button for Flutter app then IDE Intellij IDEA shows a message on console "Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock..."

Nothing happens after message.

Comment: What version of Flutter are you using? Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: which IDE you are using

Comment: Try killing terminal

Comment: if it not solves try Kill all dart processes and try again or restart the computer.

Comment: @F-1 I am using Flutter 0.7.3

Comment: Do you have `flutter packages pub build_runner watch` running? Can be https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14703

Answer (score 2):

In my case, following command in Terminal or cmd helped (as suggested by Günter):

```
killall -9 dart
```

On Windows (as suggested by upupming):

```
taskkill /F /IM dart.exe
```

or remove this file

```
<YOUR FLUTTER FOLDER>/bin/cache/lockfile
```

This releases the occupied lock and makes you able to run other commands.

Answer (score 1):

Stop any instance of flutter IDE's ([IntelliJ]/[Android Studio]/[VS Code]) and check for the existence of a file named `lockfile` in location `[flutter_installation_folder]/bin/cache/`. If any, delete it and restart your favorite IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with flutter command on *git bash for windows*
then I tried `flutter.bat <COMMAND>` it resolved by issue.

You can check out this Github issues for more info

- [#58993](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58993)
- [#61739](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61739)

Answer (score 0):

if your inside some directory and trying to run the code .
ex: c:\programfile\login\ios>
It says you to remove the startup lock. - The same thing happened to me.

For this just type "**exit"**
`ex: c:\programfile\login\ios>exit`

-this worked for me. I came out of the loop